# SSRS: Main report outputs just a blank page

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

SSRS: I have a main report with 2 sub-reports. First sub-report contains 4 tables and 2 charts and second sub-report contains 9 charts.

The main report has 6 parameters to choose from. The deal is when sub-reports are ran separately, its working fine(shows-up tables/charts/matrices even when it doesn't contain any data). But when main report is ran, it just shows-up blank page (no tables or charts or matrix..). This happens only for very few parameters(that has data to feed just charts on sub-report-1)

Did any of you face a similar problem and fixed it? I would really appreciate all your help! Thanks!

Comment: 1 lesson I learned with SSRS is that you don't need subreports unlike Crystal reports. You can create datasets that are driven by your parameters.

Comment: Usually this issue occurs if the subreport is not in the same directory as the main report. Can you confirm they are in the same location? I assume it is not working in VS? Also which versions are you using?

Comment: Try hard coding the parameters to the sub reports and seeing if it works then. If it does then double check what you think you are passing in

Comment: This is an indication that a report is not running because required parameters are missing.

Comment: @HolmesIV -  sub reports  are in the same location and yes it doesn't work in the VS and Reporting Services as well. I use SQL Server Data Tools 14.0.60629.0

Comment: @JasonWebber - yeah hard coding to sub reports works, but haven't tried it to the main report. I will try that now. Thanks for the tip..

Comment: @niktrs - I believe I have passed all the right parameters because it works for most of the parameters but just show a blank page for very few parameters(although when you hard code those few parameters for sub-reports separately, it works fine). Any advice that you can think of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to just return zeros for that data field of the dataset and ran the main-report and it worked fine! I hope this helps if anyone has similar issues..